# Stop front-end from auto-scrolling notebook to show output

Tags: front-end, notebooks, output

I have made a simple "percent complete" output to track my `For` loop, where I incrementally print values and then delete the output right before printing the next value. I want the output to remain on a single line, just as I have it.

```
startvalue = 1;
stopvalue = 70;
For[n = startvalue, n <= stopvalue, n++,
  If[Mod[(n - startvalue), 10] == 0,
    NotebookFind[SelectedNotebook[], "PrintTemporary", All, CellStyle];
    NotebookDelete[];
    PrintTemporary[
      StringJoin[
        "Percent Complete: ", 
        ToString[Round[(n-startvalue)*100/(stopvalue - startvalue), 0.1]]]]
  ]
]
```

What's annoying me is that every time `PrintTemporary` is output, the Mathematica window adjusts to put the output in view. Basically, every few seconds, my screen keeps jumping back to this `For` loop. How do I make it stop readjusting every time something is printed? I have looked at `PrintAction` and `EvaluationCompletionAction` but am not having any luck.

Comment: Have you looked into `Monitor`?