# Stop AutoScroll with PrintTemporary

Tags: printing, scrolling

I would like the workaround in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157183/stop-notebook-from-auto-scrolling-upon-printing) thread, but for PrintTemporary instead of Print.

In particular, I have followed the answer from @b3m2a1 (which works fine for Print) and tried to adapt it to PrintTemporary as well, but with no success...

I am using Mathematica 13.